# Sair do git log ou git diff

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal

Rodei o comando `git log` e visualizei todo o conteúdo, até chegar ao final conforme o print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, não conisgo fazer mais nada nessa janela de terminal. Já tentei escrever `exit`, digitar `Ctrl+C` e nada. Como faço para sair desse comando?

Answer (score 1):

O que ocorre é que o git carrega um [programa `less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)), que permite que o log seja escrolável. Para sair desse programa, basta digitar `q`. Para objter ajuda, digite `h`